# Why the cancelation of eclipse update is so slow?

Tags: eclipse

Cancelation of eclipse update would take 3-4 minutes, Why?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Eclipse is bloated, the plugins are even more bloated.  I use Eclipse, have the same problems.  This is a network request though, so your network could be slow, or the remote server could be slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time software has a cancel button it is not (usually) killing the process/thread that you are working on.  You can see this same cancel (and wait) behavior in many applications.  This is why the Mac has Force Quit and Windows has Exit Now for applications that don't seem to be quiting.

So at the code level, why this is happening is that you have likely only set a flag that says, "stop doing this once you're done with whatever loop you're in right now".  What happens is that you set the flag, but the loop is nowhere near complete and doesn't check every once in a while that the cancel flag has been triggered.  So there likely isn't much you can do about it besides download the source code and submit a patch.

Comment: I would just add that most of the time it isn't an issue of code not checking for cancelation often enough. Usually, the issue is that the code is blocked on network call which may not return until a timeout or that canceling safely is an expensive operation (there is a lot of temporary state to remove). Cancel isn't interpreted as "abort at all costs" request. The code will only cancel the job when it is safe to do so.

Comment: I agree.  What you could do though is run the network request with NIO so that you can check for a cancellation request in your main loop.  If you think you might have a long network request, let the user cancel out of it.